# Android Delete row from local database

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, eclipse

I am trying to delete record from local database ..  Where i can update the record but not able to delete the record .. I am not getting any error but still records not get deleted from local database.. Here is the code..

```
db.deleteReading(complaintNo);
```

---

```
public void deleteReading(String id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_READINGS, COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO  +"="+ id, null)  ;  //COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO is available in my readings table
    db.close();

}
```

Please guide me where i am getting wrong

Comment: do you need to have a transaction?

Comment: try this , `int result = db.delete(TABLE_READINGS, COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO  +"="+ id, null);` and print the value of `result`. If it is `0` that means your row is not getting deleted. First check this part.

Comment: hiie Kedarnath, thanks for the reply.. yes i am getting reply as 0 .. and its not deleted

Comment: 0 means it is not deleting from the database. What is the data type of Complaint NO ?

Comment: its data type is TEXT

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're not enclosing the string in single quotes:

```
db.delete(TABLE_READINGS, COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO  +"='"+ id + "'", null);
```

Or you can use the more common method, and pass the string as a "where arg":

```
db.delete(TABLE_READINGS, COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO  +"=?", new String[] {id});
```

Comment: Yeah i tried this but still not deleted record.. where when i put value of id as hard coded it gets deleted .. and i checked the value of id as well by printing it in logs

Comment: So if you print the value of `id` to the log, it gives you MyValue, and if you replace it in the code with `COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO + "='MyValue'"` it deletes the record? Can you give post your CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
    TABLE_READINGS + "("
    + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"  + COLUMN_STATUS + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_CON_NUMBER + " TEXT,"   + COLUMN_REMARK + " TEXT," + COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO + " TEXT" + ")";

Comment: I'm guessing there's some difference between the argument you're giving the `deleteReading` function, and the actual data in the DB - for example, space characters. Can you show the output of `Log.e("TAG", "*" + id + "*");`

Comment: yeah sure.. here it is..
02-24 14:25:58.381: E/TAG(11991): *31657*

Comment: :yeah sure.. here it is..
*31657*

Comment: My fault for using asterisks. Anyway, you're saying it does work if the delete condition is `COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO + "='31657'"`?

Comment: yes if i use hard coded value  then it does work...  ;

Comment: Can you please show us the output of `Log.e("TAG", Integer.toString(id.length()));`

Comment: Hiie sorry for the late reply.. its giving TAG 5... means its length is also same

Comment: Can you also post TABLE_READINGS and COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO?

Comment: yeah sure..

String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_READINGS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_STATUS + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_CON_NUMBER + " TEXT," + COLUMN_REMARK + " TEXT," + COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO + " TEXT" + ")";

Comment: I'm specifically asking for the values of TABLE_READINGS and COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO - `String TABLE_READINGS = ...` and `String COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO = ...`

Comment: String TABLE_READINGS = "readings"; and String COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO = complaint_no.. this is what you are asking for..?

Comment: Assuming you have a complaint_no 31657, can you run exactly the following code: `String otherId = "31657"; db.beginTransaction(); Log.e("TAG1", Integer.toString(db.delete(TABLE_READINGS, COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO+"='"+id+"'", null))); db.endTransaction(); db.beginTransaction(); Log.e("TAG2", Integer.toString(db.delete(TABLE_READINGS, COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO+"='"+otherId+"'", null))); db.endTransaction(); db.beginTransaction(); Log.e("TAG3", Integer.toString(db.delete(TABLE_READINGS, COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO+"='31657'", null))); db.endTransaction();`

Comment: Hiie Paf , for TAG2 i am getting response as 1..  its deleting from database.. others are not..

Comment: That doesn't make much sense - if both TAG2 and TAG3 use 31657, how can it be that the first found that record and the second didn't? Do you have other running threads, editing the same DB concurrently?

Comment: sorry by mistake i've changed the TAG3's complaint no as 157909 actually this complaints nos are getting from web service.. so ive adjust according that ..

Comment: does it like id has not proper value (or in not proper format) because when i entered hard coded value the record gets deleted perfectly as i've said earlier but not using variable id. but i've printed the value of id in logcat as well and its looking perfect in logcat ..

Comment: Can you try to add to the start of the function: `Log.e("TAG1", id); id = new Integer(id).toString(); Log.e("TAG2", id);` And check the output, and whether the deletion succeeds after this added code?

Comment: yeah i've added this as well but still no luck. :(  .. Don't know what's going on ?

Comment: I'm still unable to understand from your comments what's working and what's not, and there's obviously some crucial information missing. You'll have to provide a more complete question - more code, and input/output example - enough to further investigate the problem.

Comment: Are you doing `complaintNo.replace("\"", "");` or are you doing `complaintNo = complaintNo.replace("\"", "");` ?

Comment: see, in my activity i am writting this..

db.deleteReading(complaintNo); // this complaintNo is coming from web service in json formatt.. like "31657" so i remove this "" quotations using  complaintNo.replace("\"", ""); then 

in my database file i've written..
public void deleteReading(String id) throws SQLException{


Log.e("TAG11", id); 
id = new Integer(id).toString();
Log.e("TAG22", id);
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


  db.beginTransaction();
  Log.e("TAG1", Integer.toString(db.delete(TABLE_READINGS, COLUMN_BU+"='"+id+"'", null)));
  db.endTransaction(); 




}

Comment: complaintNo2 = complaintNo.replace("\"", "");

Comment: sry**

public void deleteReading(String id) throws SQLException{ Log.e("TAG11", id); id = new Integer(id).toString(); Log.e("TAG22", id); SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); db.beginTransaction(); Log.e("TAG1", Integer.toString(db.delete(TABLE_READINGS, COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO+"='"+id+"'", null))); db.endTransaction(); }

Comment: What **exactly** is getting printed to the logcat when you run this code? What do you get for TAG11, TAG22, and TAG1?

Comment: TAG11  31657
TAG22  31657 and TAG1 0

Comment: Please add `Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_READINGS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO+"='"+id+"'"); c.moveToNext(); Log.e("TAG0", Integer.toString(c.getInteger(0))); c.close();` - Right before `db.beginTransaction();`

Comment: getting response TAG0 as 0

Comment: Sorry, but your `id` simply isn't in the DB. As I said before, there's obviously more to your application than these lines of code, and I'm having trouble understanding what's going on there without a lot more context.

Comment: Hiie Paf..i was doing silly mistake.. now its getting response as 1 for delete but when i open my database file, the record is still there where as log showing 1. means deleted.

Comment: That's probably because you left the `beginTransaction() - endTransaction()` calls. Remove both of them, so that just the `delete()` remains.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in your query..

```
int temp=db.delete(TABLE_READINGS, COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO  +"="+ id, null)  ;
Log.d("query value",temp);
```

instead of this try this

```
int temp=db.delete(TABLE_READINGS, COLUMN_COMPLAINT_NO  +"='"+ id+"'", null)  ;
///////// print it in logcat
Log.d("query value",temp);
```

Comment: in both cases you are getting 0?